# VBA Deleting Rows based on value from multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

Every morning I need to filter out phonenumbers from an export. I need to filter through a excel document and delete rows where the phonenumber is correctly filled in. The document looks like this:

[image]

The rows need to be deleted when:

1. When COM_Soort is not G or T
2. When Landcode is not NL, BE or Empty.
3. COM_SOORT = G, Landcode = NL, Waarde starts with 06 and is 10 numbers
   long (Does not contain strange characters and such.)
4. COM_SOORT = T, Landcode = NL, Waarde starts with 0, does not start with 06 and is 10 numbers
   long (Does not contain strange characters and such.)
5. COM_SOORT = G, Landcode = BE, Waarde starts with 04 and is 10 numbers
   long (Does not contain strange characters and such.)
6. COM_SOORT = T, Landcode = BE, Waarde starts with 0, does not start with 04 and is 9 numbers
   long (Does not contain strange characters and such.)

[image]

I am trying to make a macro with VBA that automates this process. This is my first time doing this so bear with me. I am currently stuck with the following:

1. I need to run the code as different macros otherwise it only deletes the columns and then just stops, no error etc.
2. I don't know how to implement that it checks wether 'Waarde' contains somethings else than numbers
3. I don't know how to implement that when 'Waarde' starts with 0 it needs to be deleted except when it starts with 06 or 04 depending what the value of COM_SOORT and Landcode is.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteColumns()
    
    Dim Unused As Range
    Set Unused = Range("A:H,K:K")
    Unused.Delete
        
End Sub


Sub DeleteComSoort()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim rowNum As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For rowNum = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        If Range("B" & rowNum).Value <> "G" And Range("B" & rowNum).Value <> "T" Then Rows(rowNum).Delete
    Next rowNum

End Sub

Sub DeleteLandCode()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim rowNum As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For rowNum = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        If Range("C" & rowNum).Value <> "NL" And Range("C" & rowNum).Value <> "BE" And Range("C" & rowNum).Value <> "a" Then Rows(rowNum).Delete
    Next rowNum

End Sub

Sub DeleteRow()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim rowNum As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For rowNum = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        If Range("B" & rowNum).Value = "G" And Range("C" & rowNum).Value = "NL" And Len(Range("D" & rowNum).Value) = 10 And Range("D" & rowNum).Value Like "06*" Then
            Rows(rowNum).Delete
        ElseIf Range("B" & rowNum).Value = "G" And Range("C" & rowNum).Value = "BE" And Len(Range("D" & rowNum).Value) = 10 And Range("D" & rowNum).Value Like "04*" Then
            Rows(rowNum).Delete
        ElseIf Range("B" & rowNum).Value = "T" And Range("C" & rowNum).Value = "NL" And Len(Range("D" & rowNum).Value) = 10 And Range("D" & rowNum).Value Like "0*" Then
            Rows(rowNum).Delete
        ElseIf Range("B" & rowNum).Value = "T" And Range("C" & rowNum).Value = "BE" And Len(Range("D" & rowNum).Value) = 9 And Range("D" & rowNum).Value Like "0*" Then
            Rows(rowNum).Delete
        End If
    Next rowNum

End Sub
```

I hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: In the attached picture "COM_Soort" looks to be column J:J and in your code you check  "G" and "T" in column B:B... Where should this column be found?

Comment: @FaneDuru Unused columns will be deleted using DeleteColumns. I edited the picture so that it's more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please. It should be very fast for big range size, deleting all rows at once:

```
Sub DeleteRowsAccCriteria()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, i As Long, rngDel As Range, boolDel As Boolean, Unused As Range

 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your sheet
   Set Unused = sh.Range("A:H,K:K")
   Unused.Delete

 lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
 
 sh.UsedRange.Columns(1).Interior.Color = xlNone 'for testing period, to clean the green cells interior
 For i = 2 To lastRow
    If sh.Range("B" & i).Value <> "G" And sh.Range("B" & i).Value <> "T" Then
        boolDel = True
    ElseIf sh.Range("C" & i).Value <> "NL" And _
            sh.Range("C" & i).Value <> "BE" And _
            Not IsEmpty(sh.Range("C" & i).Value) Then
        boolDel = True
    ElseIf sh.Range("B" & i).Value = "T" And _
           sh.Range("C" & i).Value = "NL" And _
           left(sh.Range("D" & i).Value, 1) = "0" And _
           left(sh.Range("D" & i).Value, 2) <> "06" And _
           Len(sh.Range("D" & i).Value) = 10 And _
           sh.Range("D" & i).Value Like "##########" Then
        boolDel = True
    ElseIf sh.Range("B" & i).Value = "G" And _
           sh.Range("C" & i).Value = "NL" And _
           left(sh.Range("D" & i).Value, 2) = "06" And _
           Len(sh.Range("D" & i).Value) = 10 And _
           sh.Range("D" & i).Value Like "##########" Then
        boolDel = True
    ElseIf sh.Range("B" & i).Value = "G" And _
           sh.Range("C" & i).Value = "BE" And _
           left(sh.Range("D" & i).Value, 2) = "04" And _
           Len(sh.Range("D" & i).Value) = 10 And _
           sh.Range("D" & i).Value Like "##########" Then
        boolDel = True
    ElseIf sh.Range("B" & i).Value = "T" And _
           sh.Range("C" & i).Value = "BE" And _
           left(sh.Range("D" & i).Value, 1) = "0" And _
           left(sh.Range("D" & i).Value, 2) <> "04" And _
           Len(sh.Range("D" & i).Value) = 9 And _
           sh.Range("D" & i).Value Like "#########" Then
        boolDel = True
    End If
    If boolDel Then
        If rngDel Is Nothing Then
            Set rngDel = sh.Range("A" & i)
        Else
            Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, sh.Range("A" & i))
        End If
    End If
    boolDel = False
 Next
 If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then
    'rngDel.EntireRow.Delete xlUp
    rngDel.Interior.Color = vbGreen
 End If
End Sub
```

The above code only makes the interior of the cells in A:A green, for the row to be deleted. ***This is only for the testing period***. If everything goes well, you must only un-comment the line `rngDel.EntireRow.Delete xlUp` and comment/delete the following one (`rngDel.Interior.Color = vbGreen`) and `sh.UsedRange.Columns(1).Interior.Color = xlNone`.

Comment: @Mr J.: Didn't you find some time to test the code?

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. I tried it just now and it deleted everything. I am currently searching why it does that.

Comment: @Mr J.: This only means that you **did not refresh the page** (this one) and copied the first version... If it would be the last one, it would not delete **anything**. It only makes green the cells of A:A column, for the rows to be deleted. It is written in the answer what it is about... :)

Comment: I tried both. The first one deleted everything and the second one made all the cells in the first column green.

Comment: @Mr J.: I tested it... Let me check if I kept exactly the structure of your second picture... In fact, I will post  a link to the workbook...

Comment: @Mr J.: Please, download and test the Workbook from [here](https://easyupload.io/djdwf). It will stay there only 7 days... It is very important that the columns structure to be as in the workbook. I (only) think that I correctly reproduced your picture. Please, check also that and let me know where the mistake is...

Comment: .: It says that the File is not found. But I think I found out why it deleted everything. The unused columns need to be deleted first. Currently the IF statement checks the values in the wrong column. I added the delete statement and now it works. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @Mr J.: I maybe copied a wrong link address... I think I know what happened. The last digit was 9 and I thought I did not press Shift to add a parenthesis. Try [here](https://easyupload.io/djdwf9), please.

Comment: Yes in your workbook it worked because you already had deleted the unused rows.

Comment: @Mr J.:  But, you told me to forget about J:J column and use your second picture... Anyhow, glad it works for you, too! :)